# There are No Non-trivial Rational Function Solutions to $n=4$ Fermat's Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Pardon me for the homework-like question, I'm just trying to better understand how we go about using infinite descent.

#### Problem Statement

Suppose we have rational functions $f,g \in \mathbb C[t]$. We want to prove that these have degree 0 if $f^4(t)+g^4(t) = 1$, and we want to do so utilizing infinite descent.

**note:** I know how to do it for the $n=3$ case via infinite descent utilizing the roots of unity, but I'm having trouble applying the same workings to this example.

#### Current working so far

Let $f = \frac pr$ and $g = \frac qr$ for co-prime $p,q,r \in \mathbb C[t]$. Then plugging in and rearranging gives
$$p^4(t)+q^4(t)=r^4(t).$$ From here, I rearrange and expand the above:
$$(p(t)+r(t))(p(t)-r(t))(p(t)+ir(t))(p(t)-ir(t)) = -q^4(t).$$

My idea from here is to set new polynomials $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ s.t. one of the parts of the above product is equal to a corresponding polynomial to the 4th power, claiming that the degree of one of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ is one fourth the degree of one of $p,q,r$. If that were the case, then I could use proof by infinite descent to then prove the claim.

#### Query

However, after playing around with the terms, I'm quite certain it's not doable, at least not how I'm doing it. Am I on the right track, or do I need to rethink how I go about this? (Any hints would be appreciated!)

Comment: The classical proof for integers is to use the cases $x^4+y^4=z^2$ and $x^4+y^2=z^4$ together - have you looked at that proof?

Comment: @KReiser I have not! I know something like that exists for the non-solvability of $x^4+y^4=z^4$ in the integers, but I don't know how it applies to rational functions in the complex numbers. I'll look it up now!

Comment: The  factors on the left are pairwise coprime, hence for each factor, its roots all have order  a multiple of $4$. In other words, each factor is a fourth power. This leads to $p(t)^2\pm r(t)^2=s_\pm(t)^4$, for example

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah so I can then have $p^4(t)-r^4(t) = (s_+(t)s_-(t))^4$, with $s_+(t)s_-(t)$ having half the degree of $p$ or $r$, then rearrange so I have $p^4(t)+(\sqrt[4]{-1}s_+(t)s_-(t))=r^4(t)$?